# Compositing the stage's last frame

Tags: actionscript-3

I've created a series of classes that can be used to generate and render images. I want to store a copy of the last frame displayed so I can mix it with the current frame to create a video sustain effect. A brief overview of the classes involved in this example:

- `MasterContainer`: a subclass of `Sprite` used as the main display object. Generative classes are placed in the `MasterContainer`, and redrawn when the container is told to render
- `CustomWave`: a subclass of `Shape` used to contain, draw, and manipulate a `GraphicsPath` object. One of the aforementioned 'generative classes'

My current attempt involves the use of two `MasterContainer` objects - one for the current frame, and one for the last frame. If I'm not mistaken, the current appearance of one `MasterContainer` (and its children) can be copied to the other with a command like `lastMaster.graphics.copyFrom(master.graphics);`. Consider the following code:

```
var time:Number;
var master:MasterContainer = new MasterContainer();  //current frame
var lastMaster:MasterContainer = new MasterContainer();  // last frame
var wave:CustomWave = new CustomWave(new <Number>[0,0,0,0],0xffffff,5);  //generator for current frame
master.RegisterComponent(wave);  //adds CustomWave and registers with the rendering loop
addChild(lastMaster);  //add last frame to stage
addChild(master);  //add current frame to stage
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, perFrame);


function perFrame(event:Event):void{
    time = 0.001 * getTimer();
    lastMaster.graphics.copyFrom(master.graphics);  //copy previous frame's graphics
    UpdatePoints();  //update the path of the CustomWave
    UpdateColor();  //update the color of the CustomWave
    master.fireRenderCannon();  //redraw objects registered to master
}
```

This seems to work in theory, but as far as I can tell `lastMaster` ends up with no visible graphics content even though `master` renders as expected. I've tried several times to test whether this is the case, and am pretty convinced that that it is, but am newish to AS3 and am concerned I am overlooking something - the code looks like it should work. Does anyone have suggestions on how to test this properly? Are there obvious defects within this code that would cause `lastMaster` to be visually blank? Is there an better way of accomplishing my goal?

I think I'm in over my head on this... I would love any input. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the path of the `CustomWave` is initialized to [0,0,0,0], but the first call to `UpdatePoints` will cause the path to be nontrivial.

Comment: I have to ask, copyFrom and graphics draw methods are rather expensive. Since, at least from your code, you do not seem to do any programmatic animations, why not use bitmap data instead, then you can just copy the object with `copyPixels()` or `draw()`?

Comment: I'll figured that keeping generators in a vector form would facilitate better interop between them and their control methods... I'm not sure what I would do to replace the `drawGraphicsData` method, but I'd be interested in hearing your advice in that regard. I figured that creating bitmaps for each generator and compositing them would be more expensive. Is this not the case?

Comment: They both have their cons that's for sure. In terms of "expensive", I'd argue they are expensive in different ways. Bitmaps take up a larger amount of memory, but performance wise they are the fastest way to draw/render. If you use the draw() it is much slower than copyPixels(), I'd say both are faster than redrawing the entire graphics object using vectors, but I'd be willing to test it and get back to you.

Comment: Considering this is for real-time rendering, I'd say that memory is less of a concern than performance. I'm not sure how I'd draw a series of lines without using the `GraphicsPath` object, or something similar... ideas?

Comment: You're correct, using the graphics object for drawing is perfectly fine. What I'm saying is instead of using copyFrom(), which will redraw  a graphics object, use a BitmapData object and copyPixels for that frame. Basically anytime you aren't transforming your graphics object in anyway, replace copyFrom() in the graphics object with copyPixels() implementation from the BitmapData object.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense! I was a little confused, seeing as the bitmaps would have to be redrawn anyway every time a property of the generator changed... seemed like drawing performance difference between that and using vectors would be negligible, not to mention harder to handle in bitmap form. I've got an idea of how to simplify things on Nicholas' answer - would be interested in hearing your thoughts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49431/discussion-between-bennett-yeates-and-nate)

Comment: Oh, man, this is huge, actually... easy to adjust the coordinates, AND I can handle the sustain mentioned with a `ColorTransform` instead of a Pixelbender kernel. Sweet!

Comment: Nailed it thanks to our chat! My solution is below - you already know the details, more or less, but check out that kick*** screencap~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments made by Bennet and Nicolas, it became obvious that my requirements were (nearly) impossible without a fair amount of redesign. The changes made are as follows:

- Generators are no longer `DisplayObject`s. They are only used to calculate vectors containing the `IGraphicsData` objects necessary to draw the generated graphic with the `drawGraphicsData` method.
- `MasterContainer` is now a shape subclass that retrieves the `Vector.<IGraphicsData>` from each registered generator in order to draw the output.
- A bitmap subclass is used to render the contents of the `MasterContainer`, combining it with a color-dampened version of the previous frame.

An abridged version of the bitmap subclass:

```
private var constantSustain:Number;
private var linearSustain:Number;
private var sustain:ColorTransform;
private var lastFrame:BitmapData;

public function BitmapManipulator(constantSustain:Number = 0.998, linearSustain:Number = 0.98) {
    this.constantSustain = Math.min(Math.max(constantSustain, 0), 1);
    this.linearSustain = Math.min(Math.max(linearSustain, 0), 1);
    this.UpdateSustain();
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, OnAddedToStage)
}

private function UpdateSustain():void {
    var constantRelease:Number = 255 * (this.constantSustain - 1);
    this.sustain = new ColorTransform(this.linearSustain, this.linearSustain, this.linearSustain, 1,
                                      constantRelease, constantRelease, constantRelease, 0);
}

private function OnAddedToStage(event:Event) {
    this.lastFrame = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true, 0);
}

public function DrawFrame(container:MasterContainer):void {      
    this.lastFrame.draw(container);
    this.bitmapData = lastFrame;
    this.lastFrame = this.bitmapData
    this.lastFrame.colorTransform(getBounds(this), this.sustain);
}
```

...and finally the results @60fps when using an indigo sine wave of shifting phase as the input for the `CustomWave`:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

After you copied graphics, what do you try to do with it?
Method `copyFrom` works as clocks, without any problems. Isn't here logic bug in your code?

```
function perFrame(event:Event):void{
    time = 0.001 * getTimer();
    lastMaster.graphics.copyFrom(master.graphics);  //Here
    //master.graphics.copyFrom(lastMaster.graphics);
    UpdatePoints();  
    UpdateColor();  
    master.fireRenderCannon();
}
```

Example of `copyFrom`, it works fine with any complexity of graphics:

```
var complex: Shape = new Shape();
adobeExample(complex.graphics);
var test2: Shape = new Shape();
test2.graphics.copyFrom(complex.graphics);
addChild(test2);

private function adobeExample(graphics: Graphics):void{
    // define the line style
    graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000);

    // define the fill
    graphics.beginFill(0x666699);//set the color

    // establish a new Vector object for the commands parameter
    var star_commands:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();

    // use  the Vector array push() method to add moveTo() and lineTo() values
    // 1 moveTo command followed by 3 lineTo commands
    star_commands.push(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2);

    // establish a new Vector object for the data parameter
    var star_coord:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();

    // use the Vector array push() method to add a set of coordinate pairs
    star_coord.push(0,0, 75,50, 100,0, 125,50, 200,0, 150,75, 200,100, 150,125, 200,200, 125,150, 100,200, 75,150, 0,200, 50,125, 0,100, 50,75, 0,0);
    graphics.drawPath(star_commands, star_coord);
}
```

Comment: I assume this works for nested graphics? For example: if I have a sprite with three shape children, then `newSprite.graphics.copyFrom(theSprite.graphics)` will cause `newSprite` to show the children as well?

Comment: No, Nate, if you have display objects, and call on graphics of parent `copyFrom` It will copy only graphics from the parent, without any honour to his children. So, if your magic spread across children `copyFrom` parent doesn't give you anything...

Comment: Aha... time to do some refurbishing. Is there a built-in way to composite children or their images into a single element?

Comment: If your single element will be `Bitmap`, so you could `draw` from the parent, but... I wouldn't recommend to do it ;)

Comment: Hmmm... what about turning the generators into a `Vector.<IGraphicsData>`? Then I could just combine all those vectors into a single vector, and use `drawGraphicsData` to draw all of them onto the `MasterContainer`. No children, so I don't have to worry about compositing. They'd all be stored in `MasterContainer.graphics`, too, which might simplify matters.